# Function called outside component initialization

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

i wanna to recall the onMount in my Svelte app by clicking some button, but i got this error.
Any idea would be amazing, thx :)

[image: attemp]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This does not work. Like the error says, you must call `onMount` during initialization of the component. If you need to invoke the function inside `onMount` multiple times afterwards, pull out the code into its own function.

```svelte
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  function someFunction() {
    // do stuff
  }

  onMount(someFunction)
</script>

<button on:click={someFunction}>Click me</button>
```